# Does a win32 application have one message loop? Or is it one message loop per window?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm a little bit confused about how message loops work in win32 programming. In my `WinMain` I always put the following:

```
while ( GetMessage ( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) > 0 )
{
    TranslateMessage ( &msg );
    DispatchMessage ( &msg );
}
```

This is a while loop that pretty much runs until your application stops. Does that mean you have one message loop per application rather per window?

Comment: One per thread that needs it. You can have any number of windows powered by that thread.

Comment: You have at most one message queue per thread. Usually you only set up a single message loop per message queue. Dialogs use nested message loops, that are for the most part invisible to clients; nothing you should worry about for the moment. `GetMessage` returns the first message from the thread's message queue. `TranslateMessage` translates virtual-key messages into character messages (`WM_CHAR`, `WM_DEADCHAR`, ...). The magic happens inside `DispatchMessage`. It passes the message to the correct windows' window procedures and manages everything so that messages reach the correct recipients.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [About Messages and Message Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx):

> Applications with multiple threads can include a message loop in each thread that creates a window.

Note that a message queue CAN support multiple windows... The second parameter of [`GetMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx) is the handle of the window you want to watch messages for. If `NULL` then all the windows of the thread.

As a second note, it is possible to create a message queue without windows (at least from Windows 2000 onward). It is described in the documentation for [`PostThreadMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946.aspx):

> In the thread to which the message will be posted, call [`PeekMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943.aspx) as shown here to force the system to create the message queue.

```
PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_NOREMOVE)
```